# Use switch to change button image

Tags: ios, swift, ibaction

I am trying to change the image on my button depending on the position of a switch. I am not sure how to do this. I am relatively new to code. I have managed to change the other things on the screen but not the button. I have attached my code. I put this function into the `IBAction` for the switch:

```
func updateMySwitchState(){
    if darkModeSwitch.isOn {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        removeAds.textColor = UIColor.white
        aboutText.textColor = UIColor.white
        about.textColor = UIColor.white
        backButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "backinvert-40"), for: .normal)
    } else {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        removeAds.textColor = UIColor.black
        aboutText.textColor = UIColor.black
        about.textColor = UIColor.black
        backButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "back-40"), for: .normal)
    }
}
```

Comment: Share your button/switch action code alogn with snapshot of connection inspector (Story board >> View Controller >> Connection Inspector)

Answer (score 0):

Did you connected the outlet of the button with the controller? 
 You can set both images button image in storyboard itself for normal & selected state respectively. After setting call

`backButton.setSelected(true)` for first image and 
`backButton.setSelected(false)` for the second